# How to stop/cancel an event with EventEmitter?

Tags: node.js, events, eventemitter

EventEmitter allow to chain listeners for an event. I would like to stop the listeners to be called at some point, pretty much like the `return false` or `e.preventDefault()` work on the DOM element event.

something like that :

```js
eventEmitter = new EventEmitter()

eventEmitter
  .on('connection', (e) => {
    ...
    if (...) {
      # here, cancel the event with some method.
    }
  })
  .on('connection', (e) => {
    ...
  });
```

Any input ?